# Trac roadmap summary for multiple projects

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, trac

I use separate Trac environments for each software project I work on. I find the roadmap feature in Trac very useful for reporting progress to management. Is there some way I can automatically extract the roadmap data for each project and then automatically generate a report?

An example of the kind of report I'd like to generate can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B88d07D8tZojLWwtajluTnV6clU/view?usp=sharing

I was wondering if web scraping (using beautifulsoup) might be the best way of extracting the roadmap data?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Yes, you can write a program to do it.  If you need help with that, please start the programming yourself and let us know when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm just not sure what the best approach is? Is there a Trac plugin I can use or should I use web scraping? If someone could give me a pointer in the right direction I can then give the programming a go.

Comment: One approach would be to directly query the Trac database.  After all, all the data you need is stored right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XmlRpcPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin) provides an API to Trac. You will likely be interested in [ticket.milestone](https://trac-hacks.org/rpc#rpc.ticket.milestone). I would highly suggest interacting with Trac via this API rather than web scraping. Another option would be to develop a [Trac Plugin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment) that runs queries directly against the database. Developing a plugin has the benefit that you can use functionality provided by Trac, such as the [progress bar](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/templates/progress_bar.html). You'll also implicitly get the same styling as your other Trac sites.